# Nexus 7 USB Drivers

Tags: android, debugging, usb-drive

Hi all i am very new to this, i want to debug my app in **Google nexus 7 tablet** .I am trying to install the usb driver but every time it is telling me *UNABLE TO INSTALL* the drivers.
getting frustrated with this. Please tell me how to debug this.

Link that i have followed is:

https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48309/how-do-i-get-my-nexus-7-to-show-up-in-the-adb-devices-list/49662#49662

https://superuser.com/questions/385859/how-do-i-resolve-the-error-message-usb-device-not-recognized/515823#515823

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the USB drivers for android, and for that, connect your device to the PC and then download PDA NET drivers from this link `http://pdanet.co/`